# Azure IoT Hub's RegistryManager and Service Client - singletons or not?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub

Should IoT Hub Service SDK's [RegistryManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.registrymanager) (and [ServiceClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.serviceclient?view=azure-dotnet)) be used as a singleton (HttpClient pattern) or is `using var registryManager = ...` preferred?

#### More

Looking at RegistryManager's [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/main/iothub/service/src/Registry/RegistryManager.cs) it creates its own non-static instance of [HttpClientHelper](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/929a6d36ee8dbf9f66f0a7829f8c4c0c489a9b29/iothub/device/src/Transport/Http/HttpClientHelper.cs) which creates its own non-static instance of `HttpClient` which looks like an anti-pattern. This suggests one instance of the RegistryManager is preferred and a look at its code makes me think multiple users should be OK.

However I was not able to fine a piece of documentation that says that one instance of `RegistryManager` is  supposed to be used as a singleton for the whole application.

[image]

Comment: [RegistryManager->HttpClientHelper creates a non-static HttClient wich is an antipattern](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/2420)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now documented

```
    /// This client creates lifetime long instances of <see cref="HttpClient"/> that are tied to the URI of the
    /// IoT hub specified, configure any proxy settings, and connection lease timeout.
    /// For that reason, the instances are not static and an application using this client
    /// should create and save it for all use. Repeated creation may cause
    /// <see href="https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/">socket exhaustion</see>.
```

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/pull/2423